# Swapping opposite elements of a List of Integers if either is Odd

Tags: python, list

Write a program with the definition of a function named Array_Swap() that will accept an integer list & its size as arguments and the function will swap elements in such a way that the first element is swapped with the last element, the second element is swapped with the second last element and so on, **only if anyone or both the elements are odd** and display the result.

If initially, a list of seven elements is: `[5, 16, 4, 7, 19, 8, 2]`, the contents of the list after the execution should be:
`[2, 16, 19, 7, 4, 8, 5]`.

```
def Array_Swap(List,Size):
    for i in range (Size//2):
        List[i]=List[Size//2-i]
    print(List)

L=[]
n=int(input("Enter number of elements"))
for i in range(n):
    x=int(input("Enter element"))
    L.append(x)
Array_Swap(L,len(L))
```

Comment: There is no question in this question. See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @peter I somewhat disagree. Though the question isn't *perfect*, it's a lot better than so many other questions on SO (which unfortunately stay open for too long). Its actually somewhat obvious (to us, not OP) in this case why the code doesn't work, so it's a fair question.

Comment: @costaparas I disagree. The question shows no research effort. OP has posted the text of their assignment and the non-working code with nothing else. They haven't said what the problem is, whether the results aren't as expected, or there's an error. They haven't shown trying it with a smaller amount of data. There is no effort to explain. This question is unlikely to help anyone else in future, its purpose is to get this user's homework assignment out of the way.

Comment: Ugh, you better edit your title. This title is not very good.

Answer (score 1):

The size/length of the list is not relevant because it can be obtained by `len(list)`. And even then it's not required to conditionally swap items in the list. I suggest that the `Size` parameter be removed, but considering it's an assignment, it can be given a default of `None` so that it can be ignored by the caller if desired.

The following algorithm zips the input list with its reverse to form pairs relative to their index from the front and end of the list respectively, i.e. the first and last items are paired, the second and second last are paired, etc. Once the items are paired it is simply a matter of iterating over the list and emitting the second number of the pair if either number is odd, or the first number if neither is odd - effectively swapping the pairs as required.

This is done in-place (that's what the `List[:]` does) with a list comprehension.

```
def ArraySwap(List, Size=None):
    List[:] = [b if (a % 2 or b % 2) else a
                for a, b in zip(List, reversed(List))]
    print(List)

>>> l = [5, 16, 4, 7, 19, 8, 2]
>>> ArraySwap(l)
[2, 16, 19, 7, 4, 8, 5]
>>> l
[2, 16, 19, 7, 4, 8, 5]
>>> l = list(range(1,30))
>>> ArraySwap(l)
[29, 2, 27, 4, 25, 6, 23, 8, 21, 10, 19, 12, 17, 14, 15, 16, 13, 18, 11, 20, 9, 22, 7, 24, 5, 26, 3, 28, 1]
>>> ArraySwap([1])
[1]
>>> ArraySwap([])
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To swap two elements in the list, use the pattern `a, b = b, a`.
2. If `i` is the index of a list item, it's opposite/mirror element is `-(i+1)`, or `- i - 1`.

   - so for the 0th element (first one), the mirror is `-(0+1)`, = -1
   - using that as the indexer for the element, swap the two list elements **IF**
3. check that at least one of them is odd before swapping:

```py
def Array_Swap(List,Size):
    for i in range (Size // 2):
        if List[i] % 2 == 1 or List[-(i+1)] % 2 == 1:
            List[i], List[-(i+1)] = List[-(i+1)], List[i]
    print(List)

L = [5, 16, 4, 7, 19, 8, 2]  # use your input blocks as before, this is an example
Array_Swap(L,len(L))
```

Output: `[2, 16, 19, 7, 4, 8, 5]`

(And if `L = [5, 16, 4, 7, 19, 8, 1, 2]`, output is `[2, 1, 4, 19, 7, 8, 16, 5]`.)

Btw, you don't need to pass in the size of the list as a parameter.
You could do just: `for i in range(len(List) // 2)`

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to swap two variables in Python is:

```
a, b = b, a
```

In this case, you would do:

```
lst[i], lst[size - i - 1] = lst[size - i - 1], lst[i]
```

which swaps the `i`th element with the element that is at index `size - i - 1` (i.e. the `i`th index from the end).

The other issue with your code is that it doesn't check whether either of the elements being swapped are odd, which you can resolve by adding the condition:

```
if lst[i] % 2 or lst[size - i - 1] % 2:
```

before doing the swap. This uses the modulo operator (`%`) to check the parity of the elements. Taking a number modulo 2 will return 1 if the number is odd. If either are odd (1 has a truth value of `True`), the condition would succeed and the swap will be performed.

Finally, your function was `print`ing the list, rather than `return`ing it. Its usually best to return a result and print the returned result.

The full working version, with the above three changes is as follows:

```
def list_swap(lst, size):
    for i in range(size // 2):
        if lst[i] % 2 or lst[size - i - 1] % 2:
            lst[i], lst[size - i - 1] = lst[size - i - 1], lst[i]
    return lst

l = []

n = int(input("Enter number of elements: "))
for _ in range(n):
    x = int(input("Enter element: "))
    l.append(x)

result = list_swap(l, len(l))
print(result)
```

Also note, I've changed all the variables to be lowercase, which is standard in Python.

With your shown example:

```
Enter number of elements: 7
Enter element: 5
Enter element: 16
Enter element: 4
Enter element: 7
Enter element: 19
Enter element: 8
Enter element: 2
[2, 16, 19, 7, 4, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
def Array_Swap(List, Size=None):
    if Size is None:
        Size = len(List)
    for (i, j) in zip(range(Size // 2), range(Size - 1, Size // 2, -1)):
        if List[i] % 2 or List[j] % 2:
            List[i], List[j] = List[j], List[i]
    print(List)
```

Alternatively:

- `Size` parameter is redundant since python's `list` instance knows its own size
- Use bitwise operatos `&` `|` `>>`... possibly cheaper than modulus `%` and divide `/` operations.

```
def Array_Swap(List):
    for i in range(len(List) >> 1):
        if (List[i] | List[-i-1]) & 1:
            List[i], List[-i-1] = List[-i-1], List[i]
    print(List)
```